# JQuery not opening the already opened window when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am  relatively new to JQuery. I have an anchor tag in JSP which when clicked calls a function and it in turn calls an action class. If the result is success, it has to open a window. It works fine for the first time. But when i click on the anchored url for the 2nd time, control goes to action class but it doesnt pop up the already opened window. It doesnt even open a new window. Please suggest how to resolve it ?I need to pop up the already opened window.. I am sure it is due to jquery ajax call because the functionality works fine with out using ajax jquery. But i need to use it in my scenario

Sample code:

Open W3Schools

```
function func1() {             
               $.ajax({ 
                url: "abc.do",              
                 success: function(response){                                  
                   window.open("https://www.w3schools.com","MyWindow","left=10,top=20,width=1200,height=700,scrollbars=1,resizable=1, status=1, modal=yes"); 
                    },
                    error: function(e){
                        alert('Error: ' , e);
                    }               
                     });  }
```

Comment: I added the sample code

Comment: Right, that's kind of how `window.open` is _supposed_ to work.  Did you try using `window.focus` in the case where the window has already been opened?

Comment: By the way, I've removed two tags from your question, since this is nothing to do with Java or JSP.

Comment: yes I tried window.focus but that didnt work

Comment: OK, then I'm not sure what to suggest.  Hopefully somebody cleverer than me will come along and give you a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your browser detects a pop-up and blocks it without telling your program. How are you calling your function? Usually repeated `window.open` calls will only work in an event listener like

```
button.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    func1();
});
```

So if you have it in a loop or a similar thing, there's not much you can do about pop-up protection.

Comment: Thanks for looking in to it.But I disabled popup blocker. The opened window gets reopened when clicked next time for simple code like:     window.open("https://www.w3schools.com","MyWindow","left=10,top=20,width=1200,height=700,scrollbars=1,resizable=1, status=1, modal=yes");           It doesnt work only if action class is called using ajax jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try passing an empty name to your window instead of `MyWindow`, like this:

```
function func1() {             
           $.ajax({ 
            url: "abc.do",              
            success: function(response){ window.open("https://www.w3schools.com","","left=10,top=20,width=1200,height=700,scrollbars=1,resizable=1, status=1, modal=yes"); 
                },
                error: function(e){
                    alert('Error: ' , e);
                }               
                 });  }
```